# Beginner to java and not sure what this means

Tags: java, variables, object

```
import java.util.*;

public class decimalToBinaryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a positive interger");
        number = in.nextInt();

        if (number < 0) {
            System.out.println("Not a positive interger");
        }

        else {
            System.out.print("Convert to binary is: ");
            System.out.print(binaryform(number) + ".");
        }
    }

    private static Object binaryform(int number) {

        int remainder;

        if (number <= 1) {
            System.out.print(number);
            return null;
        }

        remainder = number % 2;
        binaryform(number >> 1);
        System.out.print(remainder);
        {
            return " ";
        }
    }
}
```

In the main part of a program an `int variable` was created. In the next part is says `private static Object binaryform ( int number )`.  Is the `int number` in the `Objectrelating` to the variable I the main method?

Comment: Reading the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) or any book about Java should answer this (and numerous related questions you might have).

Comment: How about posting the code rather than describing it? We can't see your screen.

Comment: `private static Object binaryform ( int number )` is a method signature. It has a parameter of type int, called number, and returns an Object.

Comment: Sorry. Ill just copy over the code in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. The variable name `number` has nothing to do with the main method. It is a formal parameter to the method named `binaryform`. The parameter `number` only exists within the method itself. However, when `binaryform` is called, the actual value of the variable (or constant) used in the call becomes the value of `number` while the method is executing.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 3; // the name could be "number" and no behavior would change
        Object bf = binaryForm(n);
        // do something with bf
    }

    private static Object binaryform(int number) {
        // from the call above, number will have the value 3
        Object o = . . .;
        // generate or modify o from the value of number
        return o;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the int number after binaryform actually do

Comment: @tomjdog - It declares that the method takes an int as a parameter. The calling code needs to supply an int value (either an integer literal or an int variable) as an actual parameter when the method is called.

Comment: @TeddHopp so it doesn't matter what it says after int it could say number but could say anything.  Have I got that right?

Comment: @tomjdog - Exactly. The name is arbitrary and has nothing to do with any code outside the method. (Except for one case: a local variable will _shadow_ a field if they have the same name (see [here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15), for instance). This is generally considered bad practice.)

Comment: @TeddHopp when I call binaryform it sais binaryform ( number). Does it have to be number because its called binaryform ( int number )? Also does the int in binaryform ( int number ) have significance or is that also abitrary?

Comment: @tomjdog - The message picks up the name from the source; if you change the name of the formal parameter the message will change along with it. Just go ahead and try it to see the effect. The `int`, on the other hand, is critical: it is a Java keyword that specifies the type of the argument. These are all very basic features of Java. I suggest that you go through the tutorial [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html), which covers everything I've said and many other essentials skills you will need to be a Java programmer.

Comment: @TeddHopp I think ive worked it out from changing around the program.  When it is called is the number value being carried over and is that why it is in the name of the binaryform method?

Comment: @tomjdog - The only reason it's named "number" in the method is that the programmer chose that name. (And yes, this choice probably was made because the value of the variable is a number.) There's no meaning in the language to the choice of name.

Comment: @TeddHopp but am I right in thinking that after binaryform there is ( int number ) as it is passing on the value of the variable called number to the method binaryform?